# Size Of object of a class containing one or more virtual function(s)

Tags: c++

I want to know what will be the size of an object of a class containing one or more virtual functions(but only virtual functions). Everyone says the answer is 4. But as I tried to run these codes on TCWIN45, I got 2 as the output.

[image: code]

Comment: Please add code as text, not image.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, the size of an class object is **Unspecified**.

Note that implementation of dynamic dispatch is left open for compilers. Implementations can use any mechanism of their choice and they do not need to document it.

Most implementations use the ***virtual table and pointer*** mechanism wherein a virtual pointer is added to every class object and that adds an overhead. There also maybe other things that may add to the size.

Typically,

> **Size of object = Size of non-static data members + Padding bytes + Size of vptr(it applicable)**

Answer (score 2):

"TCWIN45" is an old 16 bit compiler. There, each pointer is two bytes. The typical answer (4) applies to the far more common 32 bit compilers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, it is usually the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes), but in this case, it is very likely to be an index in the global table. The compiler probably assumed that there is no more than 2^16 polymorphic classes in the whole program.

EDIT: Not necessarily in the whole program, but at least in the current class hierarchy.